# CMS Login issue - after upgrade to silverstripe 3.5.4

Tags: silverstripe

**There seems to have been a technical problem. Please click the back button, refresh your browser, and try again.**

I am facing this error on the standard /admin login form (used for logging in to the CMS).

I have done the upgrade (3.1>3.5), after that upgrade this form was working fine for a while but then it stopped working and started throwing

"There seems to have been a technical problem. Please click the back button, refresh your browser, and try again."

Upon investigation found, the Form.php in the framework class is throwing this error. Please note the framework version is now 3.5.4

Any help/pointers if someone faced the same issue upon upgrade ??

Thanks

Comment: Hi John, you'll need to provide some more information for the Stack community to help you here. For example, do you see anything in your browser console's network tab in terms of error messages? Anything in your log files? Apache (or otherwise) or PHP error logs? Without these things it's basically like saying "My website doesn't work - why?"

Answer (score 0):

I would try a `dev/build?flush=all`. I'm pretty sure that the Member class has had additional fields added after 3.1

You can always put your site in dev mode to see the errors.

Comment: I am already in the Dev mode .... and have already dev/build?flush=all Issue is that it work for a time and then start throwing this error ...

Comment: "There seems to have been a technical problem. Please click the back button, refresh your browser, and try again." refers to CSFR issues with the forms: https://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/general-questions/show/39112 . CSRF could fail if you have session issues with the PHP. Just to be sure everything is flushed did you clear the silverstripe-cache folder and recreated it. Flushing with the param should clear that but just to be sure.